# I can get an already-logged-in window clicking on a post link in chat, but not in another post. I have to re-login a lot; by design? (Safari private)

Tags: support, design, chat, hyperlinks, login

I use private browsing if/when I use macOS + Safari.

- When I right-click a link in one SE post to another SE post and open it in a new tab I must log in to SE in that tab all over again. If I don't use private browsing the window conveniently opens already logged-in.
- When I  right-click a link *in a chat room* to another SE post I must also log in again in the newly opened tab.
- BUT if I **simply click on** a link in a chat room to another SE post it opens in a new tab already logged in.

The way I go about my SE activities often has me right-click opening (and closing) a few dozen tabs per hour so the re-logging-in is noticeable overhead for me.

Is the fact that I can get a logged-in window with for an SE post from clicking in chat but not clicking in posts  *by-design?* If so, I'm curious why.

**Question:** I can get an already-logged-in window clicking on a post link in chat, but not in another post. I have to re-login a lot; by design? (Safari macOS private browsing)

Related in Apple SE: [Is there anything I can do within Safari on mac OS so that right-click opening a link within SE post to another SE post will open the tab as logged-in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/425169/143729)

Safari 14.0, macOS 10.15.7, there seems to be no difference whether I opt-in or -out of all SE cookies.

Comment: This is something specific to Safari. There's nothing in our code that would cause this behavior.

Comment: @animuson so what would be *different behavior* in private browsing in non-Safari browsers? Would right clicking post links in other post open logged-in tabs, or would clicking on links in chat open *not-logged-in* tabs? To me, user experience depends upon how the site code and the browser work together. I'm not a web developer so an easy-to-understand explanation is appreciated.

Comment: That is a question to ask someone who is more knowledgeable of Safari, not us. A website cannot override a browser's features.

Comment: @animuson In order to understand your comment better, I've queried what would a *non-Safari browser* do. What's the expected behavior for a generic browser here?

Comment: There is no expected behavior on *our* end. The browsers control entirely how private browsing / incognito / whatever work on their end. We don't. There's really just no information to give from our side.

Comment: @animuson "There is no expected behavior..." I'll have to take your word for it on that. I'd thought that web developers will always have some expectations for what the user experiences when accessing websites with browsers, e.g. "This should do x, that should do y..." and strive for the web site to meet them for the major browsers. But like I say, I'm not a web developer. Maybe in this particular case there are in fact no expectations.

Comment: @animuson I'm sure your busy, but if you'd like to write a short answer (or ping someone else who might) that would be great. *Thanks!*